# How can I turn input from a series of toggles into speed and direction?

Tags: java, scroll, arduino, processing

I'm trying to replicate the setup [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcK0TiHRPzU) made - a capacitive scrolling Arduino gadget, except I'm having the input go into a Processing sketch. I have the wiring working just fine - when I swipe my finger along the wires, the Arduino sends values into Processing. The setup has three wires alternating, so what Processing sees when a person swipes is (1, 0, 0), then (1, 1, 0), then (0, 1, 0) and so forth.

But now I've hit a bit of a roadblock - I am trying to interpret this input as scrolling (think two-finger swiping on a laptop touch pad). I'm guessing that I need to cache a certain amount of values, and then compare them to each other to figure out which direction and how fast the user is scrolling, but I don't know how to implement that in code. It seems like there would be some kind of formula that can figure this out. Or maybe this is something I can do in Arduino, and just feed Processing the ready info?

Sampling rate is arbitrary - I have it set to a 10ms delay between sampling, but I can increase or decrease that if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need a variable to store the previous input in. So maybe something like...

```
PVector prev = new PVector();
PVector current = new PVector();

void draw() {
     current = howeverYouAreGettingTheData();

     //this is your direction vector for their swiping
     PVector direction = PVector.sub(current, prev);

     //set the previous one to the current for the next calculation.
     prev.set(current.x, current.y, current.z);
}
```